How does Yarn shut down containers?

ApplicationMaster can send a request to NodeManager to close the container. At the same time, ApplicationMaster can send a heartbeat to ResourceManager to report the container to be closed.
NodeManager can obtain the container to be closed by ResourceManager through the heartbeat.

Based on the above two points, since ApplicationMaster can close the container, why does it still need to send the container to be closed to ResourceManager? Why does ResourceManager also return the container to be closed to NodeManager?
Thank you very much.
